# Adding React to HTML (without create-react-app installation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) official React Documentation on how to add React to a website.

In file main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
      </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!-- Load React. -->
        <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <!-- Load our React component. -->
        <script src = "states_clock.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In file states_clock.js

```
// states_clock.js
'use strict';

const domContainer = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function tick() {
  root.render(<Clock date={new Date()} />);
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Both files are in the same folder.
When I open the html page in chrome, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at states_clock.js:11:7)
```

The `<` being complained about is that of the `div` in the js file.

Comment: You're using JSX, which only works if it gets precompiled using Babel. The tutorial is telling you to use [this](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/0b180827c190fe4fd98b4c7f570ea4a8/raw/b9157ce933c79a4559d2aa9ff3372668cce48de7/LikeButton.js) (non-JSX component code)

Comment: @ChrisG You're right... How would I adapt that non-JSX component code to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
```

is not JavaScript syntax - it's JSX syntax.

When you do

```
<script src = "states_clock.js"> </script>
```

as you would with any normal script tag, you're telling the browser to interpret and run it as a standard JavaScript file, which doesn't work, because it isn't. Add the attribute `type="text/babel"` to the script tag so it doesn't get run as JavaScript, and so that Babel Standalone sees that it's a script tag for it to process.

```
<script src="states_clock.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

You could also write the JSX inline, like this:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
'use strict';

const domContainer = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function tick() {
  root.render(<Clock date={new Date()} />);
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution requires to install bundler like webpack, and a compiler like babel, right?
I'm still learning the ropes in Reactjs and JS in general.

Comment: No, it doesn't - it runs completely in the browser. Press "Run code snippet" to see it working, without any other setup. While compilers/bunders are great when creating *real* apps, Babel Standalone is fine for just playing around with things (such as when asking small questions on Stack Overflow)

Comment: It only seems to work, if I write the JSX inline the html file. 
When I source the code from an outside file like states_clock.js it doesn't seem to work. Why is that?

Comment: You need to have the ability to fetch the external file. I just put your HTML into an HTML file on my website, and the JSX into a separate file, and it worked fine - because a page running on my website can XMLHttpRequest another file on the same domain. But the same does not necessarily apply to files hosted on a different domain, nor for local files (such as if the HTML does not exist on a proper server, but in only a local file `file:///C:/etc`). If that's your situation, you could set up a local development server if you wanted to write the JSX in a separate file

Comment: But at that point, it'd probably be easier to just install create-react-app and go from there (which takes care of all the basic bundling and transpilation for you - no need to learn and mess with settings yourself)

Comment: Wow! From someone that usually uses Python... This is a lot of (base) work. :D 
Many thanks for all the replies in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the comment by ChrisG, I understood that we're not supposed to use JSX in this part of the tutorial.

In that spirit, here's my solution:

```
'use strict';
const e = React.createElement;
const domContainer = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

class Clock extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return e('div', null, e("h1", null, "Hello, world!"),
                    e("h2", null, "It is ", this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString(), "."));
    };
}

function tick() {
  root.render(e(Clock, {date: new Date()}, null))
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

P.S.: Here's [useful link](https://babeljs.io/repl) that transforms JSX code into non-JSX code.